# Test PayPal payments not showing up in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-soap

I'm working the Adaptive Payment .Net API samples.  I've setup my test account stuff and everything runs fine with a "success" transaction.  The only problem is I neither see debits from the payees nor credits to the seller.

What gives?

Comment: You might get a quicker (and better) answer in a PayPal forum since this question is specific to their API.

Comment: Unfortunately having no luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing was the manual step of confirming the payment from the test payee account. I didn't realize the online interaction was necessary and not scriptable. In hindsight this is obvious for security reasons ... unfortunately this will not work for my app.

Comment: Hi xanadont please I am having the same problem, can you explain me what you did? Thanks!!! LISA

Comment: Hello, this is a very old answer but - where did you have to go to approve the payment?

Comment: I am using django paypal, and there is a command - express_endpoint_for_token(nvp_obj.token, commit=True) . Doc says to Pass 'commit=True' if you will not prompt for confirmation. It acts like payment goes thru, but it is not recorded by sender or receiver

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that everything works as you expect it to in the Pay Pal Virual Terminal before you try to get the API's to work.

I had many problems getting the sandbox to work. I would get different errors with the different accounts I set up. What I ended up doing is creating a new account and then everything started to work. I had to set up three different accounts before I got the sandbox to work. The production environment worked from the jump.